# Why does jquery execute code for non-existing selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm wondering about the execution of jquery. Suppose I have a non existing ID, why does jquery still try to execute that part of the code:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#datepicker_doesnotexist" ).datepicker({
         defaultDate: new Date(date_var)   
        });
    });
```

In this case it complains that `date_var` is not defined. That is understandable and I can make checks to prevent that, etc.

I would like to know why jQuery executes this part of the code if that ID (datepicker_doesnotexist) doesn't exist. It seems highly inefficient to do it like this if it can't be tied to an element anyway.

An example:
http://jsfiddle.net/CdE3k/

Comment: It doesn't know that it doesn't exists until you've checked for it, which is the first thing the function does. However I don't know why it goes through with the function if the selector isn't found.

Comment: Because any jQuery selector results in an array (`console.log($('#nonexistantID'))`), even if that array is empty/zero-length. So, since there's clearly a result the method is attempted (which can have no effect, since there are no elements to which it should be applied).

Comment: Is it because the `.datepicker()` function will execute even when jquery object has a length of 0?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Do you know why it behaves like that? It seems very inefficient to execute code which can't be applied to elements anyway?

Comment: I could be wrong, but that's how I understand it (currently). As to 'why'? Not a clue (I'm not even sure that it *does* behave that way.)

Comment: Needs to behave that way to support chaining. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js look at line 1811...very slight performance hit of checking for empty jQuery object.

Comment: @dotjoe: Why would it need that to support chaining. It could stop at the first non-matching selector?

Comment: Then you'd get runtime exception when trying to call .datepicker() on a null object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't initialised **date_var**. This should stop the error being thrown

```
 $(function() {
    var date_var = new Date( 2012, 10, 25 );

    $( "#datepicker_doesnotexist" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: date_var   
    });
 });
```

If no elements with matching IDs are found jQuery returns a jQuery object with no elements.
The datepicker method on the returned jQuery object is still called but it just doesn't have any html elements to work with.

This is actually a good thing. If jQuery was to return undefined when no elements match an ID the above code would throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

`{defaultDate: new Date(date_var)}` is just the passing of some argument it isn't the function itself.

It is the same as doing:

```
function someFunction(date) {

}

// this will result in an error because it is not defined. Same things happens in your code.
someFuntion(undefinedVariable);
```

Simply put `date_var` is not defined yet (at for example page load), but you are trying to use it.

Comment: No, it's not the same and doesn't answer the question why code is executed for a non existing selector.

Comment: @Nin Care to explain why you think it is not the same. What I am saying is that **no function is executed at all** when that variable is called in OPs code.

Comment: I would expect jQuery to not even initialize the datepicker since the selector does not exist. Why create an object (datepicker) if it can't be tied to an element anyway. So if it wouldn't create the object, it would not need to see the undefined variable. In your example it's clear that it would execute that line but in my example it's not clear why it does that (at least not clear to me).

Comment: Whan javascript reads the code there it is not in any block (i.e. conditional block) to prevent the code from "evaluating". Perhaps [this](http://jsfiddle.net/QRUwx/) makes it clear it is exactly the same thing.

Comment: I would have expected it to behave like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a9Njk/). So check if the selector exist and only if it does, continue. If it doesn't exist, then don't continue.

Answer (score 0):

edit: it's happening because you're passing an object to that function .datepicker() and it evaluates the object as part of passing in the object.  So that's expected behavior.

Comment: It is just an object not a function

Comment: yep realized that once I pulled it into a text editor and played with it for a second :) thanks.